# Adding and Removing XML elements using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML document that contains user defined information about a parent entity.  I would like to create a XSLT to transform the XML into whatever is the currently user defined list.
The XSLT will need to ignore removed elements, add new elements, and keep the user defined order of the elements.

Example input XML:

```
    <InventoryProperties>
      <InvProp Name="Weight"
               Type="Text"
               Alignment="Right">12500</InvProp>
      <InvProp Name="Length"
               Type="Text"
               Alignemnt="Right">20.2</InvProp>
      <InvProp Name="GVW"
               Type="Text"></InvProp>
   </InventoryProperties>
```

So now the user has changed the data points collected, and doesn't want GVW anymore, but has added Height in between Weight and Length. What I have done so far is this for getting the elements I want and leaving behind the elements I no longer need:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="InventoryProperties/InvProp[@Name = 'Weight']"/>
```

Repeating for each field that is current defined.  This works fine and keeps the order as expected.  For adding the new elements I'm trying something like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates  select="InventoryProperties[not(InvProp[@Name='Height'])]"/>
 <xsl:template name="HeightTemplate"
                match="InventoryProperties[not(InvProp[@Name='Height'])]">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='Height')]|node()"/>

    <Property LabelText="HelloWorld" />
  </xsl:template>
```

And several other versions of this, but nothing is producing what I want which would be:

```
<InventoryProperties>
  <Property LabelText="Weight"
            ControlType="Text">12500</Property>
  <Property LabelText="Height"
            ControlType="Text"></Property>
  <Property LabelText="Length"
            ControlType="Text">20.2</Property>
</InventoryProperties>
```

There is no reason for the changing of the element and attribute names, I was just trying to sort through what was working and what wasn't.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. The stylesheet (in your example) should ignore elements with Name="GVW" and add an element with Name="Height" just behind "Weight if there is not already one?

Comment: @hr_117 - Yes that is correct.  The Xlst will define what are the current data points being collected.  In this example, the Xml was saved previous to the latest definition, so when the data is now presented to the end user, we need to show the current data points,   which does not include GVW but does include Height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you call a named template for each field name you want to add to the output. That named template will check to see if an element with the given `Name` attribute exists, copy it if so and create a stub with the correct attributes if not.

This shows the idea

```
<xsl:template match="InventoryProperties">
  <xsl:call-template name="inv-prop">
    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Weight'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:call-template name="inv-prop">
    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Height'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:call-template name="inv-prop">
    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Length'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="inv-prop">
  <xsl:param name="name"/>
  <xsl:variable name="selection" select="InvProp[@Name = $name]"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$selection">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$selection"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <InvProp Name="{$name}" Type="Text" Alignment="Right">
        <xsl:value-of select="InvProp[@Name = $name]"/>
      </InvProp>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <InvProp Name="Weight" Type="Text" Alignment="Right">12500</InvProp>
   <InvProp Name="Height" Type="Text" Alignment="Right"/>
   <InvProp Name="Length" Type="Text" Alignemnt="Right">20.2</InvProp>
</root>
```

Comment: Interesting.  I got so hung up with apply-templates that I had not considered something like this.  The only catch, and it is somewhat minor, is that there is no 'stub' or default in this situation, each value of the attributes is unique to each element and there are several more that I left out for brevity.  In your example, you hard-coded the Type and Alignment values which I can't do.  I added more params to pass in the other values and that seems to work.  I'm curious though, given my new case, would you still use the same solution?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should give this a try.
**Identity transform** with some hooks to ignore or add elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ingnore not wonted stuff -->
    <xsl:template match ="InvProp[@Name='GVW'] " />

    <!-- add missing stuff -->
    <xsl:template match ="InvProp[@Name='Weight'] ">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::InvProp[@Name='Height'])" >
            <InvProp Name="Height" Type="Text" Alignment="Right"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```